# Skin indentations on body mesh

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, cloth-simulation

Like the title says, I'm experimenting with making cloth and wanted to ask if there's an easy way to make skin indentations on a body mesh under a tight cloth mesh that doesn't involve sculpting or if there's a modifier that can do that. Sculpting generally doesn't always work in lots of situations.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello could you please show some pictures, also is it supposed to be animated, what kind of style, is realistic or cartoon, etc? Shapekeys could be a way to do it